# how to test if babel works and my plugins are executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, styled-components, next.js

I'm using `Next.js` for Server Side Rendering of React application (with `styled-components`) and have issue with Babel plugins I'm using to show name of the components I'm using in code.

This is my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-styled-components",
          {
            "ssr": true,
            "displayName": true,
            "preprocess": false
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": "next/babel",
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-styled-components",
          {
            "displayName": false,
            "ssr": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "modules": "commonjs"
          }
        ],
        "next/babel"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm running `cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently "tsc --watch" next`

I'm getting these lines - meaning `.babelrc` is used during copilation:

```
[1] > Using external babel configuration
[1] > Location: "...../.babelrc"
[1] > Using "webpack" config function defined in next.config.js.
```

But once I go to dev tools and see some `styled-component` I can see this: `class="sc-iyvyFf gGaJAt"` but on my code I have this definition:

```
const Title = styled.div`
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.13;
`
```

As it seems from [documentation example](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging) - I should get something like `... <button class="Button-asdf123 asdf123" /> instead of just <button class="asdf123" />.` But I don't.

After going deeper I found this [issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1103#issuecomment-324302997) ( https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1103#issuecomment-324302997 ) based on errors I get in browser console that said:

`It seems that only the server code is being transpiled and not the client code`

So Question: **How to test if babel works correctly and `.babelrc` is being used in all places?**

**P.S.** In my case those classes that I've got on client side had this prefix `sc-` meaning in my head `styled-components`. So I was not sure if the plugin from `.babelrc` works at all or it works, but I haven't set any special property in declaration of styled-components thus get this general prefix `sc-`

**UPDATE** Here is my custom next.conf.js I'm using

```
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
const { ANALYZE } = process.env
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' }
    }
  },
  webpack: function(config) {
    if (ANALYZE) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
          analyzerMode: 'server',
          analyzerPort: 8888,
          openAnalyzer: true
        })
      )
    }

    config.resolve.alias = {
      'styled-components': path.resolve('./node_modules/styled-components/')
    }

    return config
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like no one has unfortunately answered this before;

What you're seeing probably comes down to this little piece of code you posted: `tsc --watch`

If you execute TypeScript transpilation before Babel and leave it up to TypeScript to transpile to ES5, it'll transpile all tagged template literals, not giving our plugin anything to hook onto.

Since you're already using next.js you won't need to set up your Babel pipeline from scratch. Rather you only need to disable this type of transpilation in TypeScript.

I'd suggest you to set `target` inside your `tsconfig.json` to `ESNext` so that it leaves everything up to Babel.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html (See "--target")